# Is it possible to view a WPF application deployed on windows server 2003 in Windows CE 5.0 browser on client machine?

Tags: windows-mobile

Is it possible that a WPF or XBAP applciation deployed on Windows Server 2003 can be

viewed in Windows CE 5.0 browser

Thanks.

Comment: The answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183705/is-it-possible-to-view-a-silverlight-or-asp-net-3-5-website-deployed-on-iis-6-0-i will be relevant here as well

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

http://www.google.com.au/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enAU325AU325&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Windows+CE+5.0+wpf

http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.windowsce.embedded&tid=9ee99cdb-c595-42fe-9945-f82ca09805e7&cat=&lang=&cr=&sloc=&p=1

http://www.mofeel.net/1020-microsoft-public-windowsce-embedded/1573.aspx

Short answer would seem to be no but yes via silverlight in 6.0